# Jekyll: is there a good way to add some output function/templating?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I use Jekyll for some static site generation, and got to the point where I need to output some information based on template with some parameter. The easiest way to describe - output the font-awesome tag, by writing something like {% fa apple %} or @fa-apple, or anything else, instead of `<span class="icon fa fa-apple"></span>`. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using a template: `{% include font-awesome.html icon="fa fa-apple"%}`. Not really much shorter.
2. Defining your own variables. `{% capture fa_apple %}<span class="icon fa fa-apple"></span>{% endcapture %} {{fa_apple }}`. Short in usage, but laborious to generate all captures. You might be able to automate that, though.
3. Writing your own plugin for Jekyll, with a custom filter: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/filters/
4. Use [jekyll-octopod](https://jekyll-octopod.github.io/), which includes the wanted filter: [`{% icon fa-camera-retro %}`](https://jekyll-octopod.github.io/liquid_filters) . If you don't want to use the whole thing, the filter alone can be found here: https://github.com/jekyll-octopod/jekyll-octopod/blob/master/lib/jekyll/font_awesome.rb

#1 & #2 work on Github Pages where you can't install plugins, but are workarounds with obvious shortcomings. #3 and #4 only work in environments where you can use plugins, but are the more elegant solutions.

Personally, I'd go with option #4 and use only the filter. It should be easy enough to extract. If you are using GitHub Pages, building locally and pushing the already built page is not too difficult. If you are already building the site yourself, its even easier to adapt this.

---

As an aside, the best way to reduce boilerplate might be to just switch to `<i class="far fa-address-card"></i>`. Thats 16 letters of boilerplate. `{% icon fa-camera-retro %}` clocks 11 letters of boilerplate and even `{% fa fa-camera-retro %}` clocks 9 letters of boilerplate.

`<span class="icon fa fa-apple"></span>` clocks 27 letters of boilerplate. Updating bootstrap and using `i` not `span` might be the easiest way to reduce boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! So, basically, while it is possible, it is still not good / easy way to achieve this, while it seems to be quite useful.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky Adding a custom filter isn't exactly complicated, nor is building locally. If you aren't deploying to GitHub Pages, you need to do that anyways already.